# Named pipe with shell command date

Tags: linux, bash, date, busybox, named-pipes

I want to let a standard user change the system date.

So I created a named pipe. The standard user write a date to the named pipe and a root process listens to it and sets the date accordingly:

(user)

```
echo 122515502010 > /tmp/mypipe
```

(root)

```
date -s < /tmp/mypipe
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Where am I wrong?

I'm doing this from an embedded Linux (busybox) with bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

(root)

```
read line < mypipe
date -s $line
```

Thank you everybody! ;)

Comment: As a shortcut, note that `read` will automatically populate `$REPLY` (unless you override the return variable name, as done in your example)

Answer (score 0):

Why not give the user access to date via sudo ?

Comment: busybox doesn't support sudo (at least the version I'm using).